# Why does tf.train.FloatList have rounding errors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

The following code shows that when converting a python float to a `tf.train.FloatList`, then we lose precision. My understanding was that both native python [and tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord#setup) store it as float64. So why the difference?

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x =2.3
lst = tf.train.FloatList(value=[x])
reloaded = lst.value[0]  # 2.299999952316284
```

Comment: Python might fool you and not use a true float64, because you just initialized it with the literal 2.3, but for example `x = 2.1 + 0.2` would print `2.3000000000000003`

Comment: its a float32, not float64, this should be pretty obvious.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy: Which variable is float32?

Comment: FloatList stores float32's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FloatList` contains `float`s - as in, protocol buffer `float`, which is 32-bit. If you look at the `FloatList` [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/FloatList), you'll see that `value` is defined as

```
repeated float value
```

which means the `value` field contains 0 or more 32-bit protobuf `float` values.

If it was 64-bit floats, it would say

```
repeated double value
```

but it doesn't say that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What does the documentation (link in original question) then mean with "tf.train.FloatList (the following types can be coerced): float (float32), double (float64)". Would I need to define my own proto message?

Comment: It means that you can convert a float32 or a float64 to a `FloatList` with the `_float_feature` example code a few lines down. As for defining your own message type, I don't think that would help, since it wouldn't be compatible with `tf.train.Example`, and Tensorflow wouldn't know what to do with your message type in general. I'm no Tensorflow expert, though. Tensorflow might have relevant features I'm not aware of.

Comment: Ah, so it means it accepts float32 or float64, but always stores them as float32? Okay, read it completely different.